# Не удается побороть CORS в FireFox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, cors

Всем привет.
Имеется WEB API на С# и WEB интерфейс на VUE
Работает все отлично, но при авторизации через FireFox вываливается CORS
`OPTIONS` запрос также не проходит.

Настройка корсов на бэкэ:

```cs
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsPolicy, policy =>
    {
        policy
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

В прикрепленных материалах оставлю пример `OPTIONS` запроса, который возвращает Failed CORS.
При этом из любого другого браузера таких проблем нет.

Что делаю не так ?

П.с. на фронте запросы делаю через axios. Вручную никакие заголовки не добавлю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: OPTIONS запрос может закешиться браузером, если вы не выставили нужные для запрета кеширования заголовки. Crtl+F5 меня спасал. Ну либо чистка кеша.

Comment: Скорее всего вы хотите добиться эффекта, который даст AllowAnyOrigin, но будьте внимательны к возможным уязвимостям, возникающим из-за этого. Подобнее: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @aepot  я уже пробовал чистить кэш. Не помогает, к сожалению

Comment: @bearpro пробовал добавить AllowAnyOrigin. С ним у меня CORS выдают все браузеры :). А с вариантом, описанным в посте не работает только Лисица

Comment: А что в ответе на OPTIONS?